# Backbone - How to design for situation involving duplicate models

Tags: backbone.js

Take this hypothetical app where you can view contact information for all your friends on a social network.

Search for one friend and a contact card is displayed in the results. Within a contact card is the friends name but also links to all their friends. If you click one of those links the relevant contact card is prepended to the results. This allows you to drill through.

Normally just creating a collection of friends and an associated resultsView to orchestrate would suffice. Each model can hold an instance to its own view.  But in this situation its possible for a duplicate model to be introduced. Ie.

Adam to=> Paul back_to=> Adam (adam would be in pauls friends list due to reciprocal friendship).

Perhaps im trying to force a visual design onto collections of models but collections do offer events out of the box (which are great for handling appending and removal of cards from the results). Im probably overthinking this but since im fairly novice at backbone cant figure it out.

Whats the best approach here?

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at either [Pathable's supermodel](http://pathable.github.com/supermodel/) or [Backbone-Relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational).

Both are mixin/add-ons for the model/collection system within Backbone to prevent duplicative data in the way (I believe) you are describing.

I prefer supermodel a little more because it feels a little cleaner from an API perspective.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I need duplicate behaviour and by default Backbone doesn't permit dups in collections.

Comment: @robodisco Not from your description: from what I can see you have a list of contacts. Each contact contains a list of friends (you could make this as simple as an array of IDs representing those friends).  Then you can write a filter for the collection getting the list of ids from the single collection.  You only need each model once in the collection this way.